# Must IIS be explictly enabled for remote administration?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use IIS Manager to connect to IIS running on a remote server.  The remote server is Windows Server 2003 SP2. I keep getting "Could not connect to the specified computer.  Details: Unable to connect to the remote server."  Is there anything to do on the remote server to enable it for remote administration?  [Microsoft documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324282) makes no mention of this.

If it is of any importance, I am doing this from IIS Manager on a Windows Server 2008 R2.  I am able to RDP from this server to the remote server, but as TS is running in Administration mode I keep hitting the two user limit.  So for IIS I would just like to do it from IIS Manager instead of logging in fully to the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the IIS Manager on 2008 R2, since that is for managing IIS 7. You need to explicitly install the IIS 6 Manager feature to connect to an IIS 6 instance.

Answer (score -1):

You should to configure the server to accept to be remotely controlled

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGHC0sbe17Y
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpzAsRkjV40

Comment: A textual summary instead of a utube link might be much more archival.